# Possible causes of a crazy engine?

Tags: stall, vibration, fiat, uno

My car started becoming crazy all of a sudden. The engine keeps:

- stalling out of nowhere even if i am waiting for the traffic lights not doing anything it just stalls by itself
- for the same fuel pedal press, it keeps vibrating like one keeps pressing and releasing the gas pedal violently on the first gear making the whole car vibrate, except it does this just without anything
- sometimes when i press the gas pedal, it takes it some seconds to realize i did so, so pressing the gas pedal doesn’t do anything for like 10-15 seconds(no engine sound, no acceleration, no nothing as if it is not even pressed) and then it starts accelerating after this time it spent like it was thinking :)

The strange thing about this is that it is completely unpredictable. It sometimes does this(actually a lot of time) but some other times it just drives very smoothly. Sometimes it does so when the engine is still cold and this disappears when it warms up, but some other times it doesn’t matter whether it is hot or cold. Not to mention that the engine check light keeps blinking every 2 or 3 seconds. The car is Fiat Uno 2006 if this makes any difference and it has fuel injection system not a carburetor, so what could be the cause of this craziness and how to diagnose it?

**UPDATE:** I had the codes read. What was present was P0105

Comment: Are there any codes present (a Check Engine Light)? If so, what are they?

Comment: Yep this one keeps blinking as i mentioned in the question

Comment: I see that I missed that ... so, what are the codes?

Comment: The check engine light @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2

Comment: If your check engine light is illuminated or blinks it has fault codes stored in the cars computers. If you find a mechanic or someone with a car computer scanner, it can give you the codes in the computer. Many parts stores will retrieve these codes for free. If you can get these codes and post them here it can make a big difference on how much we can help you.

Comment: Okayy i didn’t get this at first because I didn’t know this existed, but i will do so as soon as I can, thanks @Jupiter

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 the code is P0105

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P0105 is a MAF electrical fault. This is most likely the real issue going on, as without the MAF (or intermittent MAF signal), it would drive the computer batty trying to keep the engine running normally. Your description lends right to this.

Considering the fault code, I'd suggest you take a look at the wiring at the MAF and up into the wiring harness. Ensure the connector doesn't have any corrosion within it. Check the wires themselves to ensure they are good at the connector (nothing loose). Ensure there's no wear/tear in the wiring or wiring loom where the MAF wires are present. Check it as far back as you can. Also, visually inspect all of the exposed wiring harness all over the engine compartment to see if there are any signs of wear or exposed wire.